# how to redirect variables to a file but not display on screen

Tags: bash, shell

I have this small code to do some data processing.

```
#!/bin/sh
export DIR=`pwd`
if [ -d "$DIR" ] 
then
    for f in "$DIR"/HistoryData*; do
    if find "$f" -newermt 2017-03-13 ! -newermt 2017-03-14 
        then
            echo "$f" >> file
        fi
        done
else
    echo "$DIR does not exists"
fi
for f in $(cat < $DIR/file);do
        awk '/CO2/ && !/VAV/{ print $0 }' "$f" >> HistoryData_CO2
    done
```

in line `echo "$f" >> file` i am trying to write the variable to file but it is also showing the value on screen. How can i suppress the value on console and just write to file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not because of the `echo` that is writing to `stdout`, but the output of `find` that writes it, just suppress it to `/dev/null`

```
if find "$f" -newermt 2017-03-13 ! -newermt 2017-03-14 > /dev/null
```

This way, you just use the return code of the `find` in the `if-clause` and the output of the command is not printed to `stdout` but suppressed to the `NULL` device.

---

But generally relying on the output of `find` is not a good way to make your code work.

```
find "$DIR" -name 'HistoryData*' -newermt 2017-03-13 ! -newermt 2017-03-14  -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do 
        echo "$line" >> file
    done
```

Comment: can you please explain what you are doing in this line `while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line`

Comment: @occasionalvisitor: It is because of the `-print0` option in `find` output, which appends the search results with a `\0` character, and `read` command de-limits on the same character to read the individual files. See more about `-print0` in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html